# Disable outbox connection resolution for incoming Response messages when using client-side callbacks

Tags: nservicebus

NServiceBus endpoint is hosted in a web api application. Endpoint is configured to use callbacks and outbox. In the context of an incoming message, outbox needs a connection string to create the outbox DB transaction and connection. I also use client-side callbacks for sending request-response messages. When the response is returned to the endpoint that made the request, the messaging pipeline again tries to resolve the connection string for creating outbox transaction. The intent of client-side callbacks is to use the response message data and not persist anything to the database. Is there a way to bypass outbox connection creating for response messages?

I'm using the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="NServiceBus.Callbacks" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.TransactionalSession" Version="6.6.4" />
```